# C++ Object Segmentation Fault (core dumped) Error

Tags: c++, class, malloc, this

I am new to C++, so please, take it easy on me, so I have the following class:

```
class DATA
{
    private:
        char* Name;
        char* Address;
        int Id;
        void initData(int size=200)
        {
            (this->Name)=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
            (this->Address)=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
        }
    public:
        void readData(void)
        {
            this->initData();
            printf("Enter Name: "); scanf("%s\n",this->Name);
            printf("Enter Address: "); scanf("%s\n",this->Address);
            printf("Enter Id: "); scanf("%d\n",&(this->Name));
        }
        void printData(void)
        {
            printf("Name: %s",this->Name);
            printf("Address: %s",this->Address);
            printf("Id: %d",this->Id);
        }
};
```

But when I initialise an object and then call the public methods, the following happens:

```
Enter Name: John Doe
Enter Address: 53 Olive, St.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So, if anyone can tell me why (I know what is segmentation fault, but don't get it why is it here).

Comment: are you coming from C or ObjectC? Few things.. `this->` is unnecessary in context of well-defined class. name lookup resolves them using context most-nested namespace or class, looking "up" only if such identifier isn't found. It's not a mistake and you CAN see such code in C++ because there  are template parameter-dependent context where such construct is required. `malloc\free` aren't used in C++. stdlib  formatted input is unsafe like your program had illustrated.

Comment: I learned C, then cast my Python OOP on the C++, I thought `this->something` is equivalent of `self.something` , so if u can, tell me the difference.
Very much thanks for reply and sorry for that stupid question.

Comment: In short, yes, it is an equivalent of `self`, though it's not a random choice  of designer that `this` is a pointer. By default it can be omitted.`this->` can be used in a template derived from an incomplete class and access that the parent method might be not obvious to compiler, or even dubious if there is global function with same name.  `this->foo` equals to  `ThisClass::operator->(this, &ThisClass::foo)`. In C++ `operator->` can be overridden! `ThisClass` might be a template and expression is dependent on template's parameters,  it might have affect on choice of operator and on deduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method `readData`

```
     printf("Enter Id: "); scanf("%d\n",&(this->Name));
```

You are supposed to take read `Id` which is an integer, but reading into string `this->Name` instead. Either

```
scanf("%d\n",&(this->Id));
```

As you are using C++, it's convenient and easier to use `cin` and `cout` than C-style `scanf` and `printf` and running into these kind of issues.

```
cin >> Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are writing C++ code don't use `char*` and `malloc`. At least use `new` or even better use `std::string`, which also works fine with `std::cin` and `std::cout`. Your example leaks memory as you are never freeing Name and Address.

The segmentation fault is caused by `scanf("%d\n",&(this->Name))`, which should be `&(this->Id)` as already pointed out.

Comment: I don't know how to use new yet, a reference to learn from it would be cool, thanks for reply & sorry for the stupid question.